# insertObject:AtIndex:0 does not work properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have this function in which the function `insertObject:AtIndex:0` behaves weird . After inserting all objects to the NSMutableArray cardViewControllers, the final element is always `nil`.I did alloc init the cardViewControllers at the beginning in the init method.

```
- (void)reloadCardViews;
{
    // Add the restaurants onto view
    [self removeAllCards];

        for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_CARDS; i++) {
            SHCCardVC *vc = [[SHCCardVC alloc] initWithAppearanceIndex:i];
            vc.delegate = self;
            [cardViewControllers insertObject:vc atIndex:0];//it's behaving weird here
            [self addChildViewController:vc];
            // set card position to center of the container
            vc.view.center = CGPointMake(_cardContainer.frame.size.width / 2, _cardContainer.frame.size.height / 2);
            [_cardContainer addSubview:vc.view];
        }
        _currentCardViewIndex = 0;
        _currentCardIndex = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure each object is allocated just before you add it to your array.

Comment: This is how I allocate the object before adding it to array:- (id)initWithAppearanceIndex:(int)index {    
    self = [self init];
    _appearIndex = index;
    return self;
}

Comment: Make sure that cardViewControllers is not nil

Comment: Whenever you say that "feature X in language Y does not work properly", you're inevitably wrong and setting yourself up as a fool.  Instead say "I don't understand what's going on."

Answer (score 1):

What does `[self removeAllCards]` do? I suspect that you call `[cardViewControllers removeAllObjects]`? Have you tried using `[cardViewControllers addObject:vc]`? If this works and the order is important, walk trough your for loop from behind with `i--`.

**Also make sure your objects are not nil and your array is mutable and also initialized. I had a similar problem with an uninitialized mutable array.**

Comment: Log your array to console and see if it's filled: NSLog(@"%@",<yourArray>); Have you tried the 'addObject' method?

Comment: 2013-03-13 22:15:31.603 iOSShowcase[50772:c07] (
    "<SHCCardVC: 0xe75d170>",
    "<SHCCardVC: 0xe75d010>",
    "<SHCCardVC: 0xe75ca00>",
    "<SHCCardVC: 0xe75c100>",
    "<SHCCardVC: 0x758f060>"
)

Comment: Okay. You've filled your array with VCs. What's weird now?

Comment: It's seems that it logs 5 non-nil objects to the console,but in the left column when I inspect the elements,the array is like this [0]=SHCCardVC * 0x0e75d010,[1]=[1]SHCCardVC * 0x0e75ca00,[2]=SHCCardVC * 0x0e75c100,[3]=SHCCardVC * 0x0758f060,[4]=id 0x00000000

Comment: [4]=id 0x00000000. Seems like this object does not get initialized correctly. Check your initWithAppearanceIndex method what happens if you pass 0 or 5?

Comment: I think there should not be any problem with that argument

Comment: If you would have thought there was a problem, you wouldn't have implemented it. ;) But have you *tested* it?

Comment: Nice.  An uninitialized array was my culprit.  This answer helped resolve my issue quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add nil objects to arrays, it's a runtime error. So something must be going weird with the retain count, that's all I can think at the moment. NSArray retains objects that are within it, so the object is being released one too many times somewhere.

Is this a possibility?

Comment: My problem is I have to add non-nil objects to array but it always ended up the final element is always nil

Comment: The final element HAS to be nil. ;) And by final element I mean element at index n in an array with count n.

Comment: no,the number of elements is 5 but the 4th element(the last one) is nil